# Remove buttons and labels from SuperView?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios7, uibutton

In .m File

```
@interface ReaderViewController ()
{
UIButton *button;
}
```

Then I create 
Two buttons using the `button` Object

```
  button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.tag=-1;
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(record:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Rec/Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(215, 110, 80, 50);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Then again I am creating one more button using`button` object

```
     button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 button.tag=1;
 [button addTarget:self
       action:@selector(record:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [button setTitle:@"Rec/Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(340, 110, 80, 50);
 [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Now I want to remove both buttons from superView??
How can i do that

I've tried this it didn't work `[button removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: is it give some error? and where did you write code for add and remove button?

Comment: Why are you creating two identical buttons (except for their tag value) and putting one on top of the other?

Comment: Like @Abizern said why are you creating two buttons here when they are identical?

Comment: Another solution is to add each button reference to an array (or even an IBOutletCollection) and you can then have them remove themselves from their superview with `[array performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (UIView* subV in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([subV isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            [subV removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

NB: this remove all buttons into you superview

Comment: it is only appropriate when you need to remove ALL buttons in a view

Comment: How can I specify only `button` objects to be removed

Comment: I don't want to remove all buttons

Comment: @iCoder you've got your solution in trojanfoe's answer

Comment: in this case you should extend the condition ( as suggested in the other answer , using the "tag" property )

Answer (score 0):

Set meaningful tag values for the buttons:

```
button.tag = 1000;
```

and

```
button.tag = 1001;
```

and then you can remove the buttons with:

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:1000] removeFromSuperview];
[[self.view viewWithTag:1001] removeFromSuperview];
```

NOTE: You don't need the instance variable `button`; you can simply use a local variable instead.

Comment: why this answer is downvoted? it gives the most reasonable solution

Comment: @AndreyChernukha My initial edit had `[[self.superview viewWithTag:...]`.

Comment: Using view tags is always a bad idea. In this case the best answer would be to create separate properties for the button so you can then access them.

Comment: @Fogmeister always a bad idea? why?